# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable error in project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, count, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on a Laravel project and I'm following a course. Everything was going just fine, until I had to add `eloquent-sluggable` to my project. That package works just fine, but now I get the following error in my project:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

I'm using that `count()` function in my view:

```
@if($comments->count() > 0)
   @forech($comments as $comment)
     //displaying single comment data
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Now my question is, why does that error gets shown now. Could it be because I did `composer update` in my project and it updated my PHP version to `7.2`, and there is a `count()` problem in that version? I'm guessing the `>=` sign changed my PHP version.  My current Laravel project configuration:

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
```

But when I run "php -v" in my project, it shows that my PHP version is 7.2 now. Is there a way I could downgrade my PHP version without loosing my project files? Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is "$comment"?

Comment: You are passing object instead of array. Count( ) function only count the array. 
First of all convert it to array.

Comment: I'm putting all the comments in that variable in my controller: $comment = Comment::all();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get around this, is by editing   error Line 1185 in 'vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php' with:

```
$originalWhereCount = is_array($query->wheres) ? count($query->wheres) : 0;
```

I don't know if this is bad for future project, but this was the only way I could get my project to work.

Comment: This is totally bad practice as you are making changes in the core file.

Comment: I know, I'll try no to do this in future projects. I just wanted to make it work by any means...

Comment: Sorry, but when you will update your composer, the custom code which you have done will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do could be solved with https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-count

This would turn your

```
@if(count($comment)>0)
   //displaying comments
@endif
```

to

```
@if($comment->count() > 0)
//displaying comments
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$comment = comment::get()->all();

@if(count($comment)>0)
  //displaying comments
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you shouldn't use in your controller:

```
$comment = Comment::all();
```

but

```
$comments = Comment::all();
```

and pass this to view as

```
return view('some_view', compact('comments'));
```

As it's collection you should use plural variable name to avoid confusion.

Now in your view you should use:

```
@if ($comments->count())
   @foreach ($comments as $comment)
      // here you display single comment data for example {{ $comment->text }}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I know, I misspelled it here on this question. I'm using it that way in the project

Comment: So if you used code I showed, you are still getting error? You are really using `count()` on `$comments` and not on `$comment` ?. Please update your question with code you really use

Comment: Updated question, still getting the same error. Do I have to change the code for every count that I have in my project now?

Comment: @zlatangoralija Not really. How are you getting your comments? Do you run just `$comments = Comment::all();` in your controller or maybe you are doing this in some different way?

Comment: I just run $comments = Comment::all(); , but I tried some suggestions above, still getting the same error...

Comment: And what is comment here? Are you sure this is `Comment` model that extends Eloquent model? If yes, it means you are doing something else in wrong way (for example you can use view composers that override this variable name with completely other value like string)

Comment: Yes, it extends Model.. But everything was working just fine until I added that new package and it upgraded my PHP version to 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do a few things:-

1. You can downgrade your PHP version.
2. You can update your syntax while executing the query:-

Change from this

```
$comment = Comment::get();
```

to this

```
$comment = Comment::get()->toArray();
```